# insertion sort algorithm in R

Tags: r, algorithm, insertion-sort

I am new in programming and i am  trying to learn about algorithms and implementing them in R. Here is my attempt at an insertion sort:

```
# insertion sort algorithm 
inserionsort_function <- function(A){
  for (j in 2:length(A)) {
    key = A[j] 
    # insert A[j] into sorted sequence A[1,...,j-1] 
    i = j - 1 
    while (i > 0 & A[j] > key) {
      A[(i + 1)] = A[i]
      i = i - 1 
    }
    A[(i + 1)] = key
  } 
} 

inserionsort_function(c(5, 2, 4, 6, 1, 3))
```

> my code run without any error but the output of my function is not true

Comment: Please post your code, not a picture of it. Also, what is your question ?

Comment: my code is as below as u see in pic:

Comment: There is no question here.

Comment: Yes, I can see that, but we can't copy and paste your picture. Please post it so we can use it, without having to type it.

Comment: #insertion sort algorithm
inserionsort_function<- function(A){
  for (j in 2:length(A)){
    key=A[j]
    #insert A[j]into  sorted sequence A[1,...,j-1]
    i=j-1
    while (i>0 & A[j]>key){
      A[(i+1)]=A[i]
      i=i-1
    }
    A[(i+1)]=key
  }
}
inserionsort_function( c(5,2,4,6,1,3))

Comment: What is the problem with the code?

Comment: I'm voting to close since this doesn't appear to be a question. Also, R is not the right language to try to reimplement basic algorithms, since they are already implemented. See `?sort` or `?order` for instance. There's non purpose to reinvent the wheel.

Comment: @nicola Learning to code is a good reason to reinvent many wheels, and if OP's ultimate purpose is to use R, then using R as a learning language makes some sense (although it isn't nearly as beginner-friendly as Python)

Comment: @JohnColeman I can't see how the "beginner-friendliness" of R or python (?) has anything to do with this question. I do agree that in the learning process one has to reinvent many wheels. But this does not apply to any wheel. If you really want to learn R, you'd better learn the existence of the functions I mentioned above, rather than trying to reimplement basic algorithms that will be highly inefficient due to how R works and is conceived. Linked list, sorting algorithm and other basic algorithms aren't any useful IMHO in learning R.

Comment: @nicola If you are really starting out with programming, at some stage you have to learn the basics of variables, loops, arrays, etc. It almost doesn't matter what you actually do when learning such things. It could be an insertion sort, it could be a numerical integration -- who cares? The point is to get your hands dirty and start coding. On the other hand - on further thought I agree that R is a poor choice for learning how to implement such basic algorithms. For example, It seems that OP is  running into the subtle semantics of `=` vs. `<<-` (since they are trying to do an in-place sort).

Comment: @nicola @ John Colemanhe reason that I chose R for programming is that I am going to do some data mining algorithm on my database and have not any experience of programming so by this way I just want  to get my hand dirty with programming

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are at least 4 problems with your code, 1 minor and 3 major:

1) There is a typo in the name, you probably meant `insertionsort_function` (which is needlessly verbose -- why not just `insertionsort`?)

2) You aren't *returning* anything. If you want to return a sorted copy of the original array, have `A` by itself be the last line of the function. R returns the last expression in a function definition.

3) `A[j] > key` should be `A[i] > key`

4) `&` (which is for vectors) should be replaced by `&&` (which is for logical conditions).

Making these changes yields:

```
insertionsort_function <- function(A){
  for (j in 2:length(A)) {
    key = A[j] 
    # insert A[j] into sorted sequence A[1,...,j-1] 
    i = j - 1 
    while (i > 0 && A[i] > key) {
      A[(i + 1)] = A[i]
      i = i - 1 
    }
    A[(i + 1)] = key
  }
  A
}
```

For example,

```
> insertionsort_function(c(5, 2, 4, 6, 1, 3))
[1] 1 2 3 4 5 6
```

I am not convinced that R is a good language for learning the absolute basics of programming. If you do want to learn programming specifically in R, I would recommend a book which explicitly uses R to teach programming. For example, I found the book [Hands-On Programming with R](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/0636920028574.do) a good place to start. It is a quick read which teaches the fundamentals of programming in an R context.

Comment: thank u for your great response. 
 I realize my mistake and by your answer, my problem gets solved.
I am going to by that book, thank u very much

Comment: @NeginZarbakhsh Another good (but opinionated) option is [Hadley's _R for Data Science_](http://r4ds.had.co.nz/), which is free unless you want a hard copy.

Comment: @ alistaire  thanks